# How to install tldextract on a Python 2.7 app in OpenShift?

Tags: python-2.7, openshift

**Desired Behaviour**

To install tldextract ([PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tldextract) and [GitHub](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract)) in a Python 2.7 application on OpenShift.

**What I've Tried**

I tried adding to `setup.py` eg:

```
install_requires=['bottle','pymongo','requests','beautifulsoup4','lxml','Beaker','pycrypto','pillow','tldextract']
```

And then importing in the application with:

```
import tldextract
```

I also tried followed [this post](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/install-python-package#comment-33682) and ran the following from the shell:

```
virtualenv $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/virtualenv --distribute
source $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/virtualenv/bin/activate
pip install tldextract
deactivate
```

but I get the same error shown below.

This was despite the previous step showing `Successfully installed tldextract`.

**Actual Behaviour**

The presence of:

```
import tldextract
```

in the application causes a 500 error.

Running tail with:

```
rhc tail -f app-root/logs/python.log [appname]
```

The error is:

```
ImportError: No module named tldextract
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I don't know how or why, but I ssh'ed into shell and ran the following and the `ImportError` is gone and the desired behaviour is occuring:

```
source ~/python/virtenv/bin/activate
pip install --log $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/inst.log https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract/archive/master.zip
```

For reference, `setup.py` still contains the following but I'm not sure if that is contributing to any functionality:

```
install_requires=['bottle','pymongo','requests','beautifulsoup4','lxml','Beaker','pycrypto','pillow','tldextract']
```

**Edit**

For reference, I was also able to follow the above steps in order to install [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow).